# Problems removing squid fro Linux 2.6

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, packages

i want to remove squid package from my Linux box kernel 2.6

```
root@t:~/devel # rpm -i squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6.i586.rpm --nodeps
        package squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6 is already installed
root@t:~/devel # rpm -e squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6.i586.rpm --nodeps
error: package squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6.i586.rpm is not installed
```

whats wrong?

Comment: The version of the Linux kernel is largely irrelevant to this kind of problem. It'd be more helpful to know what distribution you're running. (The commercial Endian Firewall package?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can found a way to uninstall:

rpm -ev squid

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the package file name when removing a package. You should use the package name. So, you can try:

```
# rpm -e squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6
```

You can confirm the correct name by listing all the packages using:

```
# rpm -qa | grep squid
```

If there is an error when trying to install the package, you can try (add --force):

```
# rpm -i --force squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6.i586.rpm --nodeps
```

Comment: thank you, but its give me same error. rpm -qa |grep squid -> squid-2.6.STABLE18-5.endian6

Comment: @haw3d: I updated my answer. Have another look.

Comment: installed but the same error

Comment: @haw3d: Eventually, are you trying to install or remove this package?

Comment: i want to uninstall these packet, actually i want to install this package by source

Comment: Try removing by just the package name, ignoring the version. Like: `rpm -e squid`. Note that by doing `--nodeps` you are saying "please break my system", which, since it's your system, you're free to do.